# Maven No sources to compile

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I try to compile simple scala spark program with maven. I use IntelliJ and am able to run my codes successfully on IntelliJ. But when I try to create jar file using maven although everything is ok maven says:

```
no source to compile
```

My directories and files are in proper order:
src -> main -> scala -> Main.scala

```
$ mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------< veribilimiokulu:maven-scala-deneme >-----------------
[INFO] Building maven-scala-deneme 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.7 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.7.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.commons:commons-crypto:jar:1.0.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.7 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ maven-scala-deneme ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ maven-scala-deneme ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.941 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-04T23:00:14+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My pom.xml file is below, I just put dependencies element:

```
    <dependencies>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0-SNAP10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the pom and file structure

Comment: did you add scala plugin configuration on your pom?

Comment: I have added pom file

Comment: As @pedrorijo91 suggested, do you have a scala plugin (like [scala-maven-plugin](https://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/usage.html)) defined and configured in your POM? Just by seeing your `mvn` logs, I guess not, so that's probably the problem here.